# Can't get a window handle?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, xlib

I've searched all over to try and find an answer to my predicament but cannot seem to find a valid answer. I'm trying to write some equivalent user32.dll code with Xlib instead so I can support Linux users. I'm of course running Linux, so I'm using Mono. Problem comes along when I cannot even grab a window handle from the Process class because it was never even implemented:

```
[MonoTODO]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[MonitoringDescription ("The handle of the main window of the process.")]
public IntPtr MainWindowHandle {
    get {
        return((IntPtr)0);
    }
}
```

([Source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mono/mono/master/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs))

This is especially frustrating because there is seemingly no alternative. I'm trying to grab a window handle like so:

```
[DllImport("libX11")]
private static extern IntPtr XOpenDisplay(IntPtr display);

[DllImport("libX11")]
private static extern int XRaiseWindow(IntPtr display, IntPtr window);

private IntPtr ApplicationHandle;
private IntPtr Display;

private void TestXlib() {
    Process process = Process.GetProcessById(myPid);

    ApplicationHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;

    Display = XOpenDisplay(IntPtr.Zero);

    XRaiseWindow(Display, ApplicationHandle);
}
```

NOTE: In place of "myPid" is a proper process ID. Replace "myPid" with a valid process ID. Yes, I did make sure the replaced "myPid" was a valid process ID and my code didn't throw any errors indicating any process IDs I used as invalid.

This doesn't crash my application, but almost every time I call XRaiseWindow it prints:

```
X11 Error encountered: 
  Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Request:     12 (0)
  Resource ID: 0x0
  Serial:      121
  Hwnd:        <null>
  Control:     <null>
```

This obviously occurs because Process.MainWindowHandle returns IntPtr.Zero. Is there no other way to get a window handle? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `process.MainWindowHandle` just does not make sense for Xlib, From a process id, you would need to walk the tree of windows to find the one that want to raise. You could look at the `C` source for `xwininfo` to see how it is done...

Comment: @SushiHangover Well, to be frank with you, I'm not a C or C++ programmer. I understand it doesn't make sense for Xlib, but I suppose I'll have to find a C++ solution. I did use xwininfo command to get a window handle. When doing `ApplicationHandle = (IntPtr)0x000000;` it works fine. But it's a hardcoded solution. I did see some code online for enumerating through windows, but again, I'm not a C or C++ programmer.

Comment: You can alway use `xwininfo` via a C# Process and parse the stdout for the window id that you need, I've done this a few times to grab the entire window tree and or just one (via name option)... not as "clean" as an API, but it "works" ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover Hi, thanks a lot! I managed to do just that, I will post some code for whoever stumbles upon this next.

Comment: @video_error Did you ever find a solution? I'm trying to solve this same problem.

Comment: Ah shit, i figured this day would come. Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/979/ I'll post the answer right now. I just kept forgetting I really did mean too.

Comment: @tayoung Solution posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I know this was forever ago that I asked this, but I'm answering it now because I kept forgetting to answer it after I found the solution myself. I originally used @SushiHangover's solution but didn't really like it because I felt relying on an external program(`xwininfo`) was a hotfix and ultimately just added another dependency. Hopefully this helps other C# developers using Mono. This code was originally written for .NET Framework 2.0. It's not fancy and isn't really documented well. My solution was just to natively enumerate the windows using Xlib myself and return **all** windows whose title's match the described title.

In X11Wrapper.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Program.PInvoke.Xlib {

    public static class X11Wrapper {

        public const string SOName = "libX11.so";

        [DllImport(SOName)]
        // See: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html#DefaultRootWindow
        public static extern IntPtr XDefaultRootWindow(IntPtr display);

        [DllImport(SOName)]
        // See: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html
        public static extern int XQueryTree(IntPtr display, IntPtr w,
                                            out IntPtr root_return, out IntPtr parent_return,
                                            out IntPtr[] children_return, out int nchildren_return);

        [DllImport(SOName)]
        // See: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XFetchName.html
        public static extern int XFetchName(IntPtr display, IntPtr w,
                                            out string window_name_return);
    }
}
```

In Linux.Utilities.cs:

```
using Program.PInvoke.Xlib;

namespace Program {

    public static partial class Utilities {

        public static bool IsUnix {
            get {
                return Environment.OSVersion.
                       Platform == PlatformID.Unix;
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr[] FindChildWindows(IntPtr display, IntPtr window,
                                                 string title, ref List<IntPtr> windows) {
            IntPtr rootWindow;
            IntPtr parentWindow;

            IntPtr[] childWindows = new IntPtr[0];

            int childWindowsLength;

            X11Wrapper.XQueryTree(display, window,
                                  out rootWindow, out parentWindow,
                                  out childWindows, out childWindowsLength);

            childWindows = new IntPtr[childWindowsLength];

            X11Wrapper.XQueryTree(display, window,
                                  out rootWindow, out parentWindow,
                                  out childWindows, out childWindowsLength);

            string windowFetchedTitle;

            X11Wrapper.XFetchName(display, window, out windowFetchedTitle);

            if(title == windowFetchedTitle &&
               !windows.Contains(window)) {
                windows.Add(window);
            }

            for(int childWindowsIndexer = 0;
                childWindowsIndexer < childWindows.Length;
                childWindowsIndexer++) {
                IntPtr childWindow = childWindows[childWindowsIndexer];

                string childWindowFetchedTitle;

                X11Wrapper.XFetchName(display, childWindow,
                                      out childWindowFetchedTitle);

                if(title == childWindowFetchedTitle &&
                   !windows.Contains(childWindow)) {
                    windows.Add(childWindow);
                }

                FindChildWindows(display, childWindow, title, ref windows);
            }

            windows.TrimExcess();

            return windows.ToArray();
        }

        public static IntPtr[] FindWindows(IntPtr display, string title) {
            List<IntPtr> windows = new List<IntPtr>();

            return FindChildWindows(display,
                                    X11Wrapper.XDefaultRootWindow(display),
                                    title,
                                    ref windows);
        }
    }
}
```

Footnote: I initially stated I wasn't a C developer(Things have changed since then and I've learned C) so I was hesitant to implement the functionality myself using interop. If you do end up using Xlib a lot more like I did then consider using [tronche](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/) as an Xlib API reference. It is in C but I found it was pretty easy to translate to PInvokable functions and marshable structs in C#. Has some good notes to take into account too. Another good resource to help translation is directly using the source to find the definitions of the low level types to help find C# equivalents. Something like this should greatly aid you: http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libx11-ddefs.html

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! This gets the window perfectly! I tried all sorts of methods and none of them worked. You've saved my butt here and I can't thank you enough!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be of some service. Good luck on your future native Linux endeavors.

Comment: Or at least it WAS getting it... now it's not. I have no idea what's going on at this point.

Comment: First of all, thanks for this. I can get the window handle now using your example. But for some reason XRaiseWindow still doesn't work for me. It doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't raise the window (I also tried XSetInputFocus but that also doesn't seem to work... ie. doesn't set keyboard 'focus' to the window). Was this it for you? Is there anything else that could be missing?

Comment: @MikeFromCanmore I'm really sorry, Mike. I don't quite know why that's happening. I originally tested/used the above code on my Chromebook Ubuntu-LXDE chroot(Works on my machine™). I don't have a real good idea why `XRaiseWindow` wouldn't just function as intended. A good place to look is into Xorg configurations/extensions which could be effecting this. If nothing is wrong there then it's possibly still not grabbing the right window handle as `XRaiseWindow` should only error if there's an invalid window handle. Mono caught the native exception and warned me but it might not warn you.

Comment: That's alright. I'll report back if I figure it out. I'm wondering if maybe the issue is with the X11 wrapper I'm using. I pulled mine from here and added the interfaces that were missing based on your example "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/584743/Programming-Xlib-with-Mono-Deve"