# Set 'foreground' window using Xlib in C# Mono

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, focus, xlib

I have a winforms application that I'm running on Linux (specifically Raspbian Stretch) using Mono. At one point, I create a Process to run a python script which creates an external window. I need to be able to set focus on this window in a fashion equivalent to the user32.dll function SetForegroundWindow() in Windows. After some reading it appears that the way to do this will invariably involve using Xlib/X11. Unfortunately I don't know where to begin, as there appears to be no user friendly entry-level documentation that I can find.

The code below works on Windows and shows essentially what I'm trying to accomplish. The python window waits for key input in order to close. However, in order for it to register the key stroke, the window needs to have focus. If the window does not have focus, then it stays up even after I dispose of the Process that I used to invoke it in the first place.

```
if (vidLinkProc != null)
{
   IntPtr h = vidLinkProc.MainWindowHandle;

   //Unfortunately I can't find a way to force the process to have focus on Linux
   // in a way similar to the user32 SetForegroundWindow method. 
   if (!IsLinux)
   {
       SetForegroundWindow(h);
   }
   SendKeys.SendWait("q");

   vidLinkProc.Close();
   vidLinkProc.Dispose();
}
```

So, in general, I suppose the question is "How do I make this work in Linux?"
More specifically, the question includes:

- Which Xlib functions do I need in order set window focus given its handle?
- How do I call them from the Mono application?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to video_error here ([Can't get a window handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449050/cant-get-a-window-handle)) I've come a little closer.

I've downloaded this X11 wrapper (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/584743/Programming-Xlib-with-Mono-Deve), adding the interfaces per the above example. This is the updated code:

```
  IntPtr h = vidLinkProc.MainWindowHandle;
  IntPtr _display = X11lib.XOpenDisplay(String.Empty);
  X11lib.XWindowAttributes windAt = new X11lib.XWindowAttributes();
  X11lib.XSetWindowAttributes setWindAt = new X11lib.XSetWindowAttributes();

  //Linux code still doesn't work :(
  if (IsLinux)
  {
     if (h != IntPtr.Zero)
     {
         X11lib.XRaiseWindow(_display, h);
         X11lib.XSetInputFocus(_display, h, X11lib.TRevertTo.RevertToParent, (TInt)0);
     }
     else
     {
         IntPtr[] allWindows = Helpers.FindWindows(_display, "RCVideo");
         if (allWindows.Count() > 0)
         {
             setWindAt.override_redirect = (TBoolean)1;
             X11lib.XChangeWindowAttributes(_display, allWindows[0], X11lib.WindowAttributeMask.CWOverrideRedirect, ref setWindAt);

             X11lib.XRaiseWindow(_display, allWindows[0}]);
             X11lib.XSetInputFocus(_display, allWindows[0], X11lib.TRevertTo.RevertToParent, (TInt)0);

             X11lib.XGetWindowAttributes(_display, allWindows[0], ref windAt);
             Console.WriteLine("overide_redirect = {0}", windAt.override_redirect);
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("No Window found!");
         }
     }
  }
  else
  {
     SetForegroundWindow(h);
  }

  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
  SendKeys.SendWait("q");
```

The first issue was that Mono does not really implement the MainWindowHandle method (always returns 0). However, with the linked sample I was able to get the window handle (at least so it appears). Next, I needed to set the override_redirect flag in order to prevent the window manager from interfering with my commands. Now I've hit another weird snag. The code above successfully sets keyboard input focus to the child window I want closed (via the call to XSetInputFocus), BUT:

- The SendKeys command doesn't work. I know the input focus is changing only because I can see my main application window losing focus and if I then manually hit the 'q' key the child window closes as expected.
- After the call to XChangeWindowAttributes, the title bar of the child window disappears and the window can no longer be adjusted or moved manually. It's just stuck there until I hit the 'q' key which closes the window.
- The call to XRaiseWindow appears to do nothing. It doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't raise the window to the top. This is somewhat beside the point however, since all I really want to do is close the window via the method described above.

So... besides the strange response to XChangeWindowAttributes and XRaiseWindow, the only issue now seems to be sending the programmatic keystroke to an external window with input focus. Why doesn't SendKeys.SendWait() work?

**EDIT 2:**

After some more research, I've discovered that playing with the window override-redirect is not the best idea, as it is meant for windows that aren't managed by the WM and otherwise can cause some funky GTK+ behaviour. I've found a different way to raise the window using a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW client message. This successfully raises the target window to the top of the stack such that it also gets input focus. My issue now, as before, is that I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to send a key press event to the window (or rather the python script behind the window... maybe this is the issue?)

```
    private void XSendKeystroke(char key, string windowTitle)
    {
        IntPtr _display = X11lib.XOpenDisplay(String.Empty);
        IntPtr rootwin = X11lib.XDefaultRootWindow(_display);
        IntPtr ActiveWindowAtom = X11lib.XInternAtom(_display, "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW", false);

        int winIndex = 0;
        int tempreturn = 0;

        XEvent ev = new XEvent();
        ev.ClientMessageEvent.type = XEventName.ClientMessage;
        ev.ClientMessageEvent.message_type = ActiveWindowAtom;
        ev.ClientMessageEvent.format = 32;
        ev.ClientMessageEvent.ptr1 = (IntPtr)1U;
        ev.ClientMessageEvent.ptr2 = (IntPtr)1U;
        ev.ClientMessageEvent.ptr3 = (IntPtr)0U;
        ev.ClientMessageEvent.ptr4 = (IntPtr)0U;
        ev.ClientMessageEvent.ptr5 = (IntPtr)0U;

        XEvent kev = new XEvent();
        kev.type = XEventName.KeyPress;
        kev.KeyEvent.type = XEventName.KeyPress;
        kev.KeyEvent.display = _display;
        kev.KeyEvent.keycode = X11lib.XKeysymToKeycode(_display, 0x0071); //q
        kev.KeyEvent.root = rootwin;
        kev.KeyEvent.same_screen = true;

        //Find windows based on title
        IntPtr[] allWindows = Helpers.FindWindows(_display, windowTitle);
        if (allWindows.Count() > 0)
        {
            //Raise window to top of stack - works!
            ev.ClientMessageEvent.window = allWindows[winIndex];
            tempreturn = (int)X11lib.XSendEvent(_display, rootwin, (TBoolean)0, (TLong)X11.EventMask.SubstructureRedirectMask, ref ev);
            X11lib.XMapRaised(_display, allWindows[winIndex]);

            //Send key press event - doesn't work :(
            kev.KeyEvent.window = allWindows[winIndex];
            tempreturn = (int)X11lib.XSendEvent(_display, allWindows[winIndex], (TBoolean)1, (TLong)X11.EventMask.NoEventMask, ref kev);
            X11lib.XFlush(_display);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Window found!");
        }

        X11lib.XCloseDisplay(_display);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I too want to bring my application to the top, after running a secondary process, did you manage to find a way?

Comment: @MarkRedman Unfortunately I never got further than what's in the edits. If all you want to do is bring the application to the top, I was able to do it using the code I posted for function XSendKeystroke() based on the application window title string.